# how to clone inner div using jquery <= 1.4

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where i am trying to use contents inside a div as template to create controls dynamically. So to explain with example: I have created a div element BaseControl as follows that will act as a template for my controls that i am going to create when user clicks on button. Then newly cloned (div) will be appended to "container" div. The problem i am encountering is that the clone does not copy div "emailEditButtonDiv" (inner div of BaseControl div). Is that expected behaviour or am i doing something wrong. How can this be resolved?

Thanks a lot
CSC

```
<div id="BaseControl">
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="controllabel" runat="server" Text="Email:" </asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="anchor" runat="server">Anchor</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <div id="emailEditButtonDiv" class="EmailControlEditDiv" style="width: 25%">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
<span>
  <input type="button" id="imgBtnAddNewLineItem" value="Add New Email" />
</span>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imgBtnAddNewLineItem').click(function (e) {
      $('#BaseControl').clone(true).appendTo('.container');
      return false;
    });
  })
</script>
```